# Windows shutdown or logoff from browser

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, shutdown

I understand the potential security consequences of allowing shutdown or logoff from a browser, but I have an application running in a locked down 'kiosk' mode, and would like to be able to offer the user a shutdown or logoff option.

Is it possible to tell Windows to logoff or shutdown from Javascript within a browser?

Comment: This isn't going to be possible without a browser extension. Javascript is sandboxed and simply doesn't have that privilege. A kiosk software package could do this, or you could write a BHO to extend IE's native capabilities.

Comment: You will be able to do with [Neutralino.js](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs) which comes with lightweight runtime

Answer (score 0):

Sorry JavaScript cannot do this. You're best bet is if the user's browser encounters a unique glitch, thus restarting their computer. I remember I once had a program that always glitched out in Internet Explorer (I don't recall if it was 5.0 or 6.0) and restarted the user's computer. Sorry I don't recall the code but it had something to do with void and a for in loop.